# Looping through a list that gets updated

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

I am working with two columns. One has a few individual numbers and the other has sums. I'd like to match up list1 and list2. At each iteration, I remove the numbers that were matched up. There will not necessarily be a match for all numbers, but I'd like to get as many as possible. How do I make sure the loop continues to iterate but terminates once all matches have been made?

Ideally, in the example below, I would like to end up with something like:

[5,6], 11\n
[2,3], 5

Of course, if the whole approach is incorrect, please feel free to advise.

Thank you for your kind help.

```
import itertools

list1=[5,6,2,3,8,7]
list2=[11,5]

combos=list(itertools.combinations(list1, 2))

for i in range(len(list1)):
    if sum(combos[i]) in list2:
        list1.remove(combos[i][0])
        list1.remove(combos[i][1])
        list2.remove(sum(combos[i]))
        combos=list(itertools.combinations(list1, 2))
        print(combos[i])
```

Comment: it shows me the following error `TypeError: 'itertools.combinations' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: If you want to work on a list of combinations, use `combos=list(itertools.combinations(list1, 2))`

Comment: Thank you, all. You are correct. In my haste to make the problem more clear, I forgot to copy one of the cells where I turned it into a list.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you want. Could you show an expected outcome, given your (example) inputs?

Comment: Are the sums always of just two numbers? If not, the problem is NP-hard. You are essentially trying to solve a system of related [subset sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) problems. It also can be viewed as a type of [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem).

Comment: They are not always just two, but I am trying to simplify the problem since a dynamic range is an issue that I run into a lot. Once I have help with that, I will take a stab at building it out to 3/4/5 numbers as well. Thank you.

Comment: Should the numbers that are summed be consecutive?

Comment: No need. Just a coincidence that it came out that way in the example.

Comment: Do you have an objective function e.g. to maximize the number of matched numbers in the second list or to minimize the number of numbers in the first list that our not part of any match? The problem has not been clearly specified. Before writing code to solve a problem, you should be clear on exactly what that problem is.

Comment: If not consecutive, things may get tricky. If you add, e.g., 8, 14 and 9 to `list2`, those can all be matched (`5+3, 6+8, 2+7`), yielding 3 matches, but most programs would first find `5+6` and `2+3` (and nothing else), yielding 2 matches. See also John Coleman's comment above.

Comment: Thank you. The example is the simplest form. In the real problem, it is unlikely there will be multiple matches so I am less worried about it. I will update the objective even though it says in the question "I would like to get as many matches as possible".

Comment: Have you considered using other types insted of lists? Smth like `collections.deque` or `set`? Are there any duplicate elements in your `list1` data?

Comment: What actually is the question? Do you want to get matches? Or do you want to update your columns state? Or do you want to receive matches while updating? May be to create absolutle new data objects that have no matches?

Comment: If your data should be updated - when should it be updated? While searching matches or after?

Comment: The problem is that "There will not necessarily be a match for all numbers, but I'd like to get as many as possible" is ambiguous. It could be interpreted as maximizing the number of items in `list1` which are involved with a match, or it could be interpreted as maximizing the number of numbers in `list2` which are involved in a match, or it even as maximizing the *total* number (in both lists) which are involved in a match. In your comment you replaced this quote by the less ambiguous "I would like to get as many *matches* as possible", which suggests the second interpretation is intended.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Indeed, the goal is to get as many items in list2 to be removed (because we matched them) already. This is why the list needs to get updated once we find these pairings. To see whether the remaining items in the first and second list have new matches (it's an iterative problem, you might say).

Answer (score 0):

This gets only one match up, but it is not the best match up :

```py
    import itertools

    list1=[5,6,2,3,8,7]
    list2=[11,5]

    combos=list(itertools.combinations(list1, 2))
    result=[]
    for i in range(len(combos)):
        if sum(combos[i]) in list2 and (combos[i][0] in list1 and combos[i][0] in list1 ):
            result.append(combos[i])
            list1.remove(combos[i][0])
            list1.remove(combos[i][1])
            list2.remove(sum(combos[i]))

    print(result)

    #Output: [(5, 6), (2, 3)]
```

For below inputs it only finds some match up and not the most number of the match ups (depending on order of combination check):

```py
    list1=[5,6,2,8,3,7]
    list2=[11,5,10,15]
    # Output: [(5, 6), (2, 8)]

    list1=[5,6,2,3,8,7]
    list2=[11,5,10,15]
    # Output: [(5, 6), (2, 3), (8, 7)]
```

Comment: Where does the 15 come from? Why are you adding numbers to list1 and list2? They should only be getting numbers removed from them once they've been matched up.

Comment: i just added the match ups to new list called "result"

Comment: Looks like you're updating list1 and list2 as well which is different than what we want.

Comment: this is a correct version of your code as you mentioned " I remove the numbers that were matched up", you were removing and updating list1,list2. and in your question there is not anything about "no updating".

Comment: if you try to execute your own code, you can see it doesn't produce the result you wanted. your code output is (2, 3). and the correct output is  [(5, 6), (2, 3)]

Comment: I understood that desired output should be [(5, 6), (2, 3), (3, 8)]

Comment: [(5, 6), (2, 3)]  is what he mentioned in question

Answer (score 0):

As far as your question is not specified enough, I assume that:

- there are two **list-like** storages with **unsorted sequence** of elements (ints);
- elements **may repeat** in both storages;
- **each** combination of **any length** from first sequence **can be** "mached" to correspondive element in second storage via special function (sum);
- **as many as possible** (or may be **all**) such matches should be found and retrieved **immediately** after get found (via yield or print);
- **all unique** elements corresponding to such matches should be removed **immediately** after get found from both storages;
- it is allowed to create **no more than one** copy per storage;
- matching algorithm should be **finite**.

The proposed solution is based on these assumptions and satisfies almost all of them. However it can be significantly simplified if you will concretize conditions - what are exact storages types? It would be nice if the data type could be `collections.deque` or `set` - removing elements from list object is quit expensive pleasure. Also if your data should be updated - when should it be updated (while searching matches - or after)? Are there any duplicate elements in data? Is it allowed to create copies of input storages? If so, what is the maximum size|number of such copies? Is it allowed to do any other changes to storages while searching matches? Should the algorithm stop after any storage becomes empty?

```
from itertools import combinations, chain

def update_data_matches(data, matches, comb_lengths, get_match, discard_all, discard_all_from):
    # itertools.combinations operates with tuple-copy of any input data,
    # which type is not tuple. We need to create one copy explicitly
    # to minimize number of created copies:
    data_copy = tuple(data)
    if isinstance(comb_lengths, int):
        combs = combinations(data_copy, comb_lengths)
    else:
        combs = chain.from_iterable(combinations(data_copy, cl) for cl in comb_lengths)
    matches_copy = frozenset(matches)
    for comb in combs:
        if (possible_match := get_match(comb)) in matches_copy:
            discard_all(matches, possible_match)
            discard_all_from(data, comb)
            yield comb

def lst_discard_all(lst, element, i=0):
    try:
        while True:
            del lst[(i := lst.index(element, i))]
    except ValueError:
        return

def lst_discard_all_from(lst, elements):
    for i in range(len(lst)-1, -1, -1):
        if lst[i] in elements:
            del lst[i]

def lstset_discard_all(lst, element):
    try:
        lst.remove(element)
    except ValueError:
        return

def lstset_discard_all_from(lst, elements):
    for e in elements:
        try:
            lst.remove(e)
        except ValueError:
            continue

def update_lst_data_matches(*args, **kwargs):
    return update_data_matches(*args, discard_all=lst_discard_all,
                               discard_all_from=lst_discard_all_from, **kwargs)

def update_set_data_matches(*args, **kwargs):
    return update_data_matches(*args, discard_all=set.discard,
                               discard_all_from=set.difference_update, **kwargs)

def update_lstset_data_matches(*args, **kwargs):
    return update_data_matches(*args, discard_all=lstset_discard_all,
                               discard_all_from=lstset_discard_all_from, **kwargs)
```

In your case:

```
data1 = [5,6,2,3,8,7]
data2 = [11,5]

for match in update_lstset_data_matches(data1, data2, 2, sum):
    print(f'{match=}', f'{sum(match)=}', f'{data1=}', f'{data2=}')
```

Result:

```
match=(5, 6) sum(match)=11 data1=[2, 3, 8, 7] data2=[5]
match=(2, 3) sum(match)=5 data1=[8, 7] data2=[]
match=(3, 8) sum(match)=11 data1=[7] data2=[]
```

Example 2: find all sum matches with combinations of all length. Related problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

```
data3 = {-7, -3, 66, -2, 5, 8}
data4 = {0, 13, -9, 4, 19}

for match in update_set_data_matches(data3, data4, range(1, len(data3)), sum):
    print(f'{match=}', f'{sum(match)=}', f'{data3=}', f'{data4=}')
```

Result:

```
match=(5, 8) sum(match)=13 data3={66, -7, -3, -2} data4={0, 4, 19, -9}
match=(-7, -2) sum(match)=-9 data3={66, -3} data4={0, 4, 19}
match=(5, -3, -2) sum(match)=0 data3={66} data4={4, 19}
match=(5, 8, -7, -2) sum(match)=4 data3={66} data4={19}
```

Example 3:

```
data5 = [11, 123, 3, 66, -2, 11, 8, 66, 3.0, 3]
data6 = [0, 13, -9, 4.0, 123, 4, 19, 0]

for match in update_lst_data_matches(data5, data6, range(1, len(data5)), sum):
    print(f'{match=}', f'{sum(match)=}', f'{data5=}', f'{data6=}')
```

Result:

```
match=(123,) sum(match)=123 data5=[11, 3, 66, -2, 11, 8, 66, 3.0, 3] data6=[0, 13, -9, 4.0, 4, 19, 0]
match=(11, 8) sum(match)=19 data5=[3, 66, -2, 66, 3.0, 3] data6=[0, 13, -9, 4.0, 4, 0]
match=(11, 8) sum(match)=19 data5=[3, 66, -2, 66, 3.0, 3] data6=[0, 13, -9, 4.0, 4, 0]
match=(3, -2, 3.0) sum(match)=4.0 data5=[66, 66] data6=[0, 13, -9, 0]
match=(3, -2, 3) sum(match)=4 data5=[66, 66] data6=[0, 13, -9, 0]
match=(-2, 3.0, 3) sum(match)=4.0 data5=[66, 66] data6=[0, 13, -9, 0]
```